# Pattern for designing a scalable web service

Tags: java, web-services, multithreading, concurrency, latency

I am writing a web service in Java which needs to handle a large number of requests / second. The general flow will be:

- Web service receives a request from client
- Returns a 'keep polling me' response to client
- Calls another web service (or
  services), and waits for them to
  respond (with a timeout)
- Client polls our web service, until
  it receives a response (with a
  timeout)

Researching on the Internet, I have found two general approaches to writing web services:

- Spawn a thread for each request
- Use the Reactor pattern (central dispatcher thread responds to IO events)

Do you have a recommendation for which approach is generally better, and what are the pros/cons of each approach? I would also appreciate pointers to examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think multi-threading.  Think asynchronously.  I happened to have just coded an async handler that ran 2,000 RPS with <10 threads in IIS.  Not sure how java works since I'm a .net guy but I gotta believe they have similar BeginXXX/EndXXX methods.  If you ever spawn a thread then you're not considering all the places your code can block:  data base IO, File I/O, web services, etc.  These are the places your performance will cause your site to be slow.

Async, Async, Async.

Chant and repeat.

Comment: Hallelujah, brother :) By 'async', do you mean non-block async IO (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592303/asynchronous-io-in-java)? More detailed will be really appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a good Java parallel to .net's begin* and end*: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t16252.html

Answer (score 0):

In addition to "No Refunds No Returns" response, I'd say yeah "Think Asynchronously" as you should be allowing your container to manage the multi-threading/scalability and high-availability issues of the web services it has deployed, this allows you to set-up things like clustering and so forth using your application container.

EDIT: So in conclusion, there isn't a pattern as such, maybe you should explore the scalability/availability features of your application container...

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronism is indeed the right approach but don't manage this yourself, use something that supports asynchronous web service invocation like JAX-WS 2.0 (which uses the `Future` interface and/or the `Executor` framework from `java.util.concurrent`). See [Asynchronous Web Service Invocation with JAX-WS 2.0](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/19/asynchronous-jax-ws-web-services.html).