# How do you create an asynchronous HTTP request in JAVA?

Tags: java, asynchronous, httprequest

I'm fairly new to Java, so this may seem obvious to some. I've worked a lot with ActionScript, which is very much event based and I love that. I recently tried to write a small bit of Java code that does a POST request, but I've been faced with the problem that it's a synchronous request, so the code execution waits for the request to complete, time out or present an error.

How can I create an asynchronous request, where the code continues the execution and a callback is invoked when the HTTP request is complete? I've glanced at threads, but I'm thinking it's overkill.

Comment: see also [bayou async http client](http://bayou.io/release/0.9/docs/http/Http_Client.html)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Note that java11 now offers a new HTTP api [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html), which supports fully asynchronous operation, using java's [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html).

It also supports a synchronous version, with calls like [send](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html#send(java.net.http.HttpRequest,java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandler)), which is synchronous, and [sendAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html#sendAsync(java.net.http.HttpRequest,java.net.http.HttpResponse.BodyHandler)), which is asynchronous.

Example of an async request (taken from the apidoc):

```java
   HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create("https://example.com/"))
        .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .POST(BodyPublishers.ofFile(Paths.get("file.json")))
        .build();
   client.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString())
        .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
        .thenAccept(System.out::println);
```

Comment: if I use java8, which API is best ?

Comment: @alen i don't know. hopefully soon everyone can use java11...

Answer (score 36):

If you are in a JEE7 environment, you must have a decent implementation of JAXRS hanging around, which would allow you to easily make asynchronous HTTP request using its client API.

This would looks like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static Future<Response> getAsyncHttp(final String url) {
        return ClientBuilder.newClient().target(url).request().async().get();
    }

    public static void main(String ...args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Future<Response> response = getAsyncHttp("http://www.nofrag.com");
        while (!response.isDone()) {
            System.out.println("Still waiting...");
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        System.out.println(response.get().readEntity(String.class));
    }
}
```

Of course, this is just using futures. If you are OK with using some more libraries, you could take a look at RxJava, the code would then look like:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    final String url = "http://www.nofrag.com";
    rx.Observable.from(ClientBuilder.newClient().target(url).request().async().get(String.class), Schedulers
            .newThread())
            .subscribe(
                    next -> System.out.println(next),
                    error -> System.err.println(error),
                    () -> System.out.println("Stream ended.")
            );
    System.out.println("Async proof");
}
```

And last but not least, if you want to reuse your async call, you might want to take a look at Hystrix, which - in addition to a bazillion super cool other stuff - would allow you to write something like this:

For example:

```
public class AsyncGetCommand extends HystrixCommand<String> {

    private final String url;

    public AsyncGetCommand(final String url) {
        super(Setter.withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("HTTP"))
                .andCommandPropertiesDefaults(HystrixCommandProperties.Setter()
                        .withExecutionIsolationThreadTimeoutInMilliseconds(5000)));
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected String run() throws Exception {
        return ClientBuilder.newClient().target(url).request().get(String.class);
    }

 }
```

Calling this command would look like:

```
public static void main(String ...args) {
    new AsyncGetCommand("http://www.nofrag.com").observe().subscribe(
            next -> System.out.println(next),
            error -> System.err.println(error),
            () -> System.out.println("Stream ended.")
    );
    System.out.println("Async proof");
}
```

PS: I know the thread is old, but it felt wrong that no ones mentions the Rx/Hystrix way in the up-voted answers.

Comment: how can I use it with proxy?

Comment: would be great if you care to elaborate on this answer,specifically the RxJava example, I see a methodcall to newThread(), which seems to imply that this code is also spins up a new thread? I'm vaguely familiar with Rx's async capabilties, so this kind of surprises me...

Comment: The Scheduler.newThread() call simply tells Rx to spin the execution on a new thread in this case - this enforcing async computing. Of course, if you already have any kind of async setup, you can use it instead pretty easily (Scheduler.from(Executor) comes to mind).

Comment: @Gank Yes, since it uses lambdas, it can't compile over 1.8. It should be easy enough to write it the long way using Consumer etc...

Comment: @psyx Do we have to unsubscribe to the observable?

Answer (score 26):

You may also want to look at [Async Http Client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client).

Answer (score 15):

Based on a link to [Apache HTTP Components](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/) on [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests#answer-2793153), I came across the Fluent facade API for HTTP Components.  [An example there](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fluent.html#d5e1274) shows how to set up a queue of asynchronous HTTP requests (and get notified of their completion/failure/cancellation).  In my case, I didn't need a queue, just one async request at a time.

Here's where I ended up (also using URIBuilder from HTTP Components, [example here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e43)).

```
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Async;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Content;
import org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
import org.apache.http.concurrent.FutureCallback;

//...

URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder();
builder.setScheme("http").setHost("myhost.com").setPath("/folder")
    .setParameter("query0", "val0")
    .setParameter("query1", "val1")
    ...;
URI requestURL = null;
try {
    requestURL = builder.build();
} catch (URISyntaxException use) {}

ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
Async async = Async.newInstance().use(threadpool);
final Request request = Request.Get(requestURL);

Future<Content> future = async.execute(request, new FutureCallback<Content>() {
    public void failed (final Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() +": "+ request);
    }
    public void completed (final Content content) {
        System.out.println("Request completed: "+ request);
        System.out.println("Response:\n"+ content.asString());
    }

    public void cancelled () {}
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You may want to take a look at this question: [Asynchronous IO in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592303/asynchronous-io-in-java)

It looks like your best bet, if you don't want to wrangle the threads yourself is a framework. The previous post mentions
Grizzly, https://grizzly.dev.java.net/, and Netty, http://www.jboss.org/netty/.

From the netty docs:

The Netty project is an effort to provide an asynchronous event-driven network application framework and tools for rapid development of maintainable high performance & high scalability protocol servers & clients.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/) also have an async http client now too:

```
/**
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.0-beta4</version>
    </dependency>
**/

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClients;
import org.apache.http.nio.IOControl;
import org.apache.http.nio.client.methods.AsyncCharConsumer;
import org.apache.http.nio.client.methods.HttpAsyncMethods;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

public class HttpTest {

  public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    final CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient = HttpAsyncClients
        .createDefault();
    httpclient.start();
    try {
      final Future<Boolean> future = httpclient.execute(
          HttpAsyncMethods.createGet("http://www.google.com/"),
          new MyResponseConsumer(), null);
      final Boolean result = future.get();
      if (result != null && result.booleanValue()) {
        System.out.println("Request successfully executed");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Request failed");
      }
      System.out.println("Shutting down");
    } finally {
      httpclient.close();
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
  }

  static class MyResponseConsumer extends AsyncCharConsumer<Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onResponseReceived(final HttpResponse response) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCharReceived(final CharBuffer buf, final IOControl ioctrl)
        throws IOException {
      while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
        System.out.print(buf.get());
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void releaseResources() {
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean buildResult(final HttpContext context) {
      return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how can I use it with proxy?

Comment: @Dejel I would assume you set the system properties as specified  here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

Comment: Calling future.get() will block the thread. Need to place this in another thread to be actually async. The HttpAsyncClients library is poorly named...

Answer (score 0):

It has to be made clear the HTTP protocol is synchronous and this has nothing to do with the programming language. Client sends a request and gets a synchronous response.

If you want to an asynchronous behavior over HTTP, this has to be built **over** HTTP (I don't know anything about ActionScript but I suppose that this is what the ActionScript does too). There are many libraries that could give you such functionality (e.g. [Jersey SSE](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html)). Note that they do somehow define dependencies between the client and the server as they do have to agree on the exact non standard communication method above HTTP.

If you cannot control both the client and the server or if you don't want to have dependencies between them, the most common approach of implementing asynchronous (e.g. event based) communication over HTTP is using the [webhooks approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook) (you can check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576278/Webhooks-webhook-URLs-and-a-sample-implementation) for an example implementation in java).

Hope I helped!

Comment: While technically true, this answer can be misleading because, regardless of what the server or HTTP protocol supports, the client implementation can have very significant performance implications depending on whether it's executing the request in a blocking manner on the same thread, a different thread in a thread pool, or ideally using non-blocking IO (NIO) where the calling thread sleeps until the OS wakes it up when the response arrives.  It sounds like the OP is interested in the client threading model rather than the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.0.x/index.html) and making the call in a separate thread. This solution is useful if you are only making one async call. If you are making multiple calls I suggest using [apache HttpAsyncClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-4.1.x/index.html) and placing the calls in a thread pool.

```
import java.lang.Thread;

import org.apache.hc.client5.http.classic.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.classic.HttpClients;

public class ApacheHttpClientExample {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (final CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {
            final HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/get");
            new Thread(() -> {
                 final String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            }).start();
        }
    }
}
```