# What's the equivalent of ASP.NET IHttpAsyncHandler in java world?

Tags: java, asp.net, architecture, frameworks

What's the equivalent of ASP.NET IHttpAsyncHandler in java world ?

Comment: see "[How do you create an asynchronous HTTP request in JAVA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142915/how-do-you-create-an-asynchronous-http-request-in-java)"

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at asynchronous support in latest Servlet specs (3.0): http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/asynchronous_support_in_servlet_3