# How to make quick http requests ? (Java)

Tags: java, json, performance, http, request

I made an application that serves as an autobuyer. Making it as fast as possible is crucial to get to the item faster than anyone else. I am using an infinite loop (i.e. for(;;)) to make continuous http requests and then parsing the JSON result.

Does anyone know how to make multiple simultaneous requests ? Mine currently does about 3 requests a second.
Also is java not appropriate for this sort of application ? Should I consider using another language maybe ?

Thank you very muuuch !

Edit: I use a search function like

```
for(;;){
search(323213, 67);
search(376753, 89);
}

public void search(int itemID, int maxPrice) {

// sets the http request with the need cookies and headers
// processes the json. If (itemId==x&&maxPrice>y) ==> call buy method

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Making requests in an infinite loop will get your IP blocked by any service that actively monitors for abuse.

If you wish to send a bunch of requests in parallel for a short period of time, spin up multiple threads and have each of them submit a request.

Java is a very capable platform for multi-threading.

Comment: Thank for the input. I'll making threads. Ran my app for hours didn't get flagged or anything, guess its because it's too slow to be signaled as an abuse lol

Comment: @user1776576: They may still notice what you are doing if they have not already.  Please respect any terms of service that may apply, and please do not overwhelm their infrastructure with requests whether or not they detect it today.

Answer (score 1):

Using a [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) you could schedule a runnable to run with a fixed rate, say every 10 seconds, without bothering about spawning the threads your self.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another post that gives a good example of how to do this with threading:
[How do you create an asynchronous HTTP request in JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142915/how-do-you-create-an-asynchronous-http-request-in-java)

If you are comfortable with JavaScript, Node.JS is another good choice for this.  Using Node.JS removes the need to worry about threading, because the request is done asynchronously.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I looked into Node.Js and it looks perfect for what I am trying to accomplish. thans again

Answer (score 0):

1. for get request String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=developer";

   ```
   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

   // add request header
   request.addHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

   HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
   ```
2. String url = "https://selfsolve.apple.com/wcResults.do";

   ```
   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

   // add header
   post.setHeader("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

   List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sn", "C02G8416DRJM"));
   urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cn", ""));
   urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("locale", ""));
   urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("caller", ""));
   urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("num", "12345"));

   post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

   HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
   ```