# Akka Actors in Java with Twitter Streaming API

Tags: java, scala, twitter, streaming

I'm interested in building something similar to "[BirdWatch](https://github.com/matthiasn/BirdWatch)" by Matthias Nehlsen, but I want to do this using Java & the Play Framework rather than Scala.

I've done some searching and I've not been able to find any definitive guide on how to set up an asynchronous connection to the Twitter Streaming API. Does anyone know of anything similar to this than I can use to learn how to create the streaming connection?

Comment: Scala provides powerful abstractions for doing async processing. If you are trying to do the same thing in Java, you may end up wasting a lot of time.

For setting up async connection in Java, you can refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142915/how-do-you-create-an-asynchronous-http-request-in-java

Since you are using Play! Framework, http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/JavaWebSockets is useful.

Comment: @VenkatSudheerReddyAedama thank you Venkat. I've found this very helpful!