# Sending a GET http request freezes my window

Tags: java, http, freeze, jwindow

I was messing around, tried to make a multiplayer game in java, made a window, a player, etc...
I then proceeded to send a request to my server to get the player positions, send them too

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
        .uri(URI.create(url))
        .build();

HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,
         HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

But whenever I send a get request, I get the response successfully, but the window freezes when it's getting the response, Any help please?

Comment: Is this code executed in the main thread?

Comment: Yeah, it is, may i ask why?

Comment: You should be sending the request [asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142915/how-do-you-create-an-asynchronous-http-request-in-java) / in a separate thread

Comment: So, that still freezes the window, here's my code on pastebin https://pastebin.com/raw/AkkCT1tB (different file) && https://pastebin.com/raw/eAGTgMFD (main file)

Comment: You're not doing an async request as @AlexRudenko suggested. You're creating an async object and doing a synchronous `get()` call on it, so essentially what you were doing before. Follow the SO post he linked to.

Comment: That worked, Thank you so much!