# Asynchronous socket I/O on Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, asynchronous

Is there a decent mechanism for doing asynchronous I/O using sockets on Android?

I'm aware of the existence of nio channels, but they don't work for me because I need to be able to use MulticastSockets and BluetoothSockets, neither of which support channels.

I'm aware the answer is probably that there isn't one, but as this is a fairly big piece of work I thought I'd ask first to be sure. And if anyone knows of a decent third-party library I might be able to use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than nio I don't know any built-in option for this problem however there is an interesting answered question on this already on SO.

Take a look at it maybe the third party libraries will help you. [Asynchronous IO in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592303/asynchronous-io-in-java)

I can't tell how well those libraries work on Android you might also have to get them Android-ready in order to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks --- unfortunately none of those really did what I wanted so I'm rolling my own. What use is a wheel if you can't reinvent it? Sigh. I'll see if I can persuade my boss to let me release the library as open source once I'm done.

Comment: You'd probably better take those away; it looks like it's not going to be open sourced. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832633/516188

but keep in mind my comment to that solution, under the solution itself.