# Scala method performance (collect or foreach or other) looping through sockets?

Tags: scala

Here are two definitions both achieving the same result:

```
  def sendTrigger(teamId:Long, data:String) {
    EngineSync.browserSockets.collect{ case ((i,(u,t)),s) => if(t==teamId) { s.send(data) } }
  }

  def sendTrigger(teamId:Long, data:String) {
    EngineSync.browserSockets.foreach{ case ((i,(u,t)),s) => if(t==teamId) { s.send(data) } }
  }
```

What's happening is I am looping through a list of sockets and filtering them to send data. Being a newbie to Scala, I am concerned about performance when this begins to scale. From what I understand `foreach` performance is poor compared to other methods, does anyone know if `collect` would fare better or if this is the wrong approach entirely?

Comment: Why don't you save a `Map` `teamId -> List(Socket)`? Lookup is cheap and you get all the relevant socket instances easily

Comment: Definitely considering that ;) how would that compare to a class that stored information about each socket (in some instances, the socket is relevant to a user and not a team)?

Comment: Performance of `foreach` is just fine. `collect` will be slower because it has to be build a new collection. Also - don't nest tuples like that; use a case class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through a fair sized collection vs. performing network IO (at least when blocking) are [entirely different scale operations](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/every-programmer-should-know), therefore I would not worry about performance issures at this phase.

If you really care about performance when scaling massively:

- Use [NIO for asynchronous socket IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592303/asynchronous-io-in-java)
- Wrap up the socket access logic inside an `Actor` (and maybe use `Future`s in clients to hide the Actors)
- Or even spare yourself the time and use [Akka's IO](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/io.html) module

Comment: Actually you're the second to suggest to me to wrap socket access in Actors. I love Akka, and I'm convinced it needs to be done. I can say, however, that the websocket framework itself is built on Netty (Webbit) so I'm not worried about it scaling...