# Java 7 Async SecureSocket?

Tags: java, ssl, asynchronous, io

Java 7 shipped with asynchronous I/O. Does anyone here know if I can use this to make async calls to a `SecureSocket`?

Rephrased: If I am using `sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket("127.0.0.1", 42)`, then using `socket.getOutputStream()` and `socket.getInputStream()` to communicate in a blocking way; what changes would I need to make to access the async functions which would allow me to re-write my code to work asynchronously?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSL/TLS in Java with Non-blocking I/O isn't new in Java 7, but was introduced in Java SE 5. This can be done using the [`SSLEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLENG) instead of sockets.

The `SSLEngine` is notoriously difficult to use. You can in principle convert between channels and `InputStream`/`OutputStream`s using the [`Channels`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html) class, but there's also quite a lot to do in terms of using the `SSLEngine` itself. Here are a few pointers:

- [Official examples in the JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLEngineSample).
- [Using SSL with Non-Blocking IO by Nuno Santos](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/11/03/ssl-nio.html).
- You could look at existing open source frameworks that use it, such as [Grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/) or [Simple](http://www.simpleframework.org/).
- Chapter 8 of [*Fundamental Networking in Java*](http://www.springer.com/computer/swe/book/978-1-84628-030-6).

Comment: I read that async I/O is better than non blocking I/O. See the responses to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592303/asynchronous-io-in-java#comment12606745_592592). It is not dramatically better, but it is supposed to be better, and it is only introduced in Java 7.

Comment: Indeed, but even with NIO2, you'll have to use channels and the `SSLEngine`. Whether the extra complexity is worth the performance improvements, I don't know. There's a [talk by J.F. Arcand (Grizzly project)](parleys.com/d/318), but it doesn't seem to talk about SSL.

Answer (score 2):

As Bruno correctly mentions, SSLEngine is the standard way of doing asynchronous SSL. But that class is *seriously* hard to use.

I came across the same problem some time ago and ended up writing my own library. There are some examples out there and of course there is also the code inside projects like Netty, etc. But neither option is robust or easily reusable.

[TLS Channel](https://github.com/marianobarrios/tls-channel) wraps an SSLEngine in a ByteBuffer and allows to use it just like normal SocketChannels.

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous IO (part of Java NIO) does not use streams but rather channels, buffers and selectors. You can definitely still connect to secure servers though. There will be a lot of changes required to your current code though, so you might not want to update to Asynch IO unless you have a very good reason.

I recommend [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/index.html) as a starting point.